# R: Providing parameters to a function?

Tags: r, function, plot

I have a function called `plot()` .  I want my function to be in a way such that if the user  just inputs `plot()` it will plot all the rows in the data that is read inside the function ( inside `plot()` data will be read )

I also want the user to be able to choose which rows he wants to plot from the data. So if the user inputs `plot(1)` , function will plot the first row. If user inputs `plot(1,3)` it'll plot the first and the third rows.

I tried doing that but I'm not sure how.

This is what I tried to do:

```
plot <- function(x){
if(x==0)
{ //reads the whole file and plots all the rows
}
else
{
//reads the specified rows and plots them
}
}
```

This works only if the user wants to plot one row as in the case of `plot(1)` , but doesn't work if the user wants more than one row (i.e `plot(1,2,3)` ).

Help?

Comment: Whatever you do, don't call the function `plot`. `plot` is a rather important function in R and you don't want to mask it.

Comment: In addition to Roland's comment, the problem with your function is that you're using `if` which is noch vectorized, i.e. it only handles input vectors of length 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test <- function(...){
  rows <- c(...)
  if(!is.null(rows) & !is.integer(rows)){stop("Input is not an integer"!)}
  if(max(rows) > nrow(data)){stop("Out of bounds!")}
  if(is.null(rows)){
    plot(data)
  }else{
    plot(data[rows,])
  }
}
```

The `...` lets you put in anything you want, so this will need some error prevention.

The function just creates a vector of the input, checks for length to see if input was given, then plots either the whole dataset (no input given) or the lines determined by the vector `rows`.

Edit: Changed first error prevention from `numeric` to `integer`.

In the long run, you will probably need more error prevention with this kind of input, but for now it should work.

Comment: I was writing the same answer, but would have suggest `if (is.null(rows))`.